# webservice download vs simple http post dowload

Tags: java

Here's the scenario,

1. Design a service to allow file download.
2. File to be downloaded will be heavy and already signed/encrypted.

I am looking for some direction/thoughts on the following:

1. Develop a simple http post and secure the service by issuing client certificates and performing client certificate validation whenever a request is made to download the file? My concern is that it will impact the server performance since files are already heavy.
2. Use a pure webservice to accomplish the task and depend on WS-Security provided? Again, files are already heavy though I can use MTOM but it has its own dependencies.

Guys, please provide some suggestions?

Comment: You should probably provide some of your own thoughts and explain what research you've done...

Comment: I am planning to go ahead with deploying servlet to allow file download on tomcat. For authentication I am planning to use mutual authentication and signature/encryption to secure the file download. We will also have to develop small utility to allow download from client machine, so we will use httpclient for that. If you have any thoughts/recommendation, please share.